# Webmatrix Database connect error using PHP

Tags: php, webmatrix

I have created a database using webmatrix which I'm unable to connect. Here is my web.config file.

```
<add connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmptySite10;User ID=sa;Password=serial" name="EmptySite10" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is my PHP connect code.

```
                $servername = ".\SQLEXPRESS";
            $username = "sa";
            $password = "serial";
            $dbname = "EmptySite10";

            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Could not connect : " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_close($conn);
```

I get the following error:

> Could not connect : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

How can I connect to database?

Answer (score 1):

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
```

enter the ip address or hostname in `$servername`.